# Can I request email only communications?

Tags: communication, email-etiquette

I am on my way out of an employee contract. Done in two months. My employer has gotten increasingly more hostile and will guilt trip me over phone like "Do you know how much time I have given you off this year?" All PTO I used was earned. Can I request for him to only communicate via email for the remainder of my time there? I want everything in writing from here on out.

Comment: You can request anything you like.  Whether your employer will honor that request is doubtful.  Just be professional and keep your mouth shut.  You're done in 2 months!

Comment: Talk to your manager and HR about these things.

Comment: In which jurisdiction are you in?

Answer (score 6):

Can you request it?  Sure.  Is it likely that your boss is going to comply with that request?  No.

If your goal is to ensure that your boss doesn't put pressure on you to stay, you're probably out of luck.  You can ensure that everything is in writing by sending a follow up email every time you have a phone call that summarizes what was discussed.  It isn't obvious to me that there is a benefit to you in having a paper trail of these conversations, however.  Unless you think that your boss is actually harassing you or violating some other company policy and you're willing to go to HR to try to have him stop, it isn't obvious what written communication is going to accomplish.

Comment: In addition to this excellent advice, I would recommend that the OP reads this book https://www.amazon.com/When-Say-No-Feel-Guilty/dp/0553263900

Answer (score -1):

I would setup my Cell Phone with a generic message "I'm unable to answer the phone right now, please send me an Email" and I would update my voicemail with something similar.

Whenever my Boss would ring, I'd ignore either use the quick answer feature (to send them a txt) or let it go to Voicemail.

Then, I'd follow up by email:

"Hi Boss,

Sorry I missed your call, what is the issue?"

Basically, don't answer the phone, ensure everything is done in writing.

Comment: That seems pretty unprofessional.  It is entirely reasonable for the OP's boss to want to speak to them, and entirely unreasonable for the OP to refuse.  2 months probably isn't long enough for this to escalate to dismissal but they'd be well and truly burning their bridges with this employer.  Justin Cave's answer of documenting and calls would create a paper trail demonstrating any bad behaviour from the boss while retaining good relations with the rest of the company.